# What should I do if I have 1 hdmi port in my gpu?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I bought a second monitor for my PC. While trying to connect it to my PC, I saw that my GPU only has x1 HDMI port, x1 DP and x1 DVI.

My first monitor is connected via the HDMI port so I only have the other 2 options available. The second monitor that I bought has x2 HDMI ports and x1 VGA port.

I have found three methods that I can use.

- First one is to buy an HDMI to DP cable.
- Second an HDMI to DVI.
- Third VGA to DVI.

I want to know if there are any downsides for having a cable that converts a certain one of those or if they all work the same. Which one is most preferable etc…

Comment: Another option: Return the second monitor and buy one that supports DP or DVI.

Comment: Well you see I want my first and second monitor to be the same, so if i return this one I would have to buy a 2 new ones.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

HDMI, DVI, and DP are all digtal and can convert exactly to one another. VGA is an analog signal; ignore the VGA.

Does your current monitor have a DisplayPort port? Otherwise, I'd convert GPU's DP to HDMI for your second monitor.

Comment: My monitor doesn't have a DP port no. So if i just buy a dp to hdmi cable it should just work like normal without any problems?

Comment: @Elias Make sure it goes the right way DisplayPort GPU signal to HDMI monitor, not the other way around.

Comment: Oke, thank you.